# Document Renaming with UIDocumentBrowserViewController

Tags: ios, uidocument, uidocumentbrowservc

I am using the "new way" of storing documents (iOS 11+) using *UIDocumentBrowserViewController*. No need for iCloud API, Entitlements etc. -- just works (under control of the separate Document Browser process).

However, I haven't figured out how to rename (i.e. move) a document programmatically this way, at least within iCloud. The standard "url.setResourceValues()" does work just fine on the local filesystem, but renders in *513/not permitted* in iCloud. Also all the former ways of doing it (using full set of iCloud capabilities & entitlements, using complex FileCoordinator orchestration etc.) don't work either when the created document actually is controlled through the document browser.

I couldn't find any reasonable documentation or example on how to use the *UIDocumentBrowser* to also move a document under it's (and somewhat my) control. There is the *UIDocumentBrowserImportModeMove* mode that might do what I need, however I have no clue how to programmatically initiate that on a given *UIDocument*.

Has anyone already made experiences to do it this way?

Thanks, habitoti

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to move a document that was returned to you by the document browser after the user picked it. You should file a bug with Apple to get one.

If this is inside your iCloud container, you can use the iCloud entitlements and `-[NSFileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:]` to get sandbox access to your container and do whatever you want inside with NSFileManager; but that won't work in iCloud outside of your container or in other file providers (Dropbox...).

Comment: Thanks, I'll file a Radar. Using the UIDocumentBrowser, you shouldn't have the need for an explicit cloud container configuration. UIDocument together with UIDocumentBrowser's value proposition is to do all the heavy lifting around ownership and permissions for you, so setResourceValue(name) should IMHO be able to do that in cooperation with the UIDocumentBrowser process.

Comment: If the file is materialized on disk... With the new File Provider APIs, some files might not exist at all until you coordinate to read them. It's to rename files that don't exist on disk or are placeholders that new API is probably needed. For files that are downloaded, I agree NSFileManager should work in an ideal world, but the cloud provider needs to be told about the move... Anyway, yes, Apple needs to find a way to make this work in every case and a radar is the way to go.

Comment: The file is already on disk/iCloud. The orchestration also for creation is "copy local -> cloud, open from there", so when I am asked to open the UIDocument, it's already there. I want to edit the resource name of the loaded UIDocument.
And it anyway doesn't work either for existing docs being opened straight from an iCloud drive.

Comment: For existing, downloaded docs in iCloud Drive, if you ask for sandbox access using URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier (don't forget to start accessing), you should be able to use NSFileManager to move them. But this doesn't solve the general problem, agreed.